# Error predict with mlr:

Tags: r, h2o, mlr

I tried to train a h2o model using the following code and make a prediction for new data, but it leads to an error. How can I avoid this error?

```
library(mlr)
a <- data.frame(y=factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0)), 
                x1=rep(c("a","b","c"), times=c(6,3,3)))
aTask <- makeClassifTask(data = a, target = "y", positive = "1")
h2oLearner <- makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", 
                          predict.type = "prob")
model <- train(h2oLearner, aTask)

b <- data.frame(x1=rep(c("a","b", "c"), times=c(3,5,4)))
pred <- predict(model, newdata=b)
```

leads to the following error:

> Error in checkPredictLearnerOutput(.learner, .model, p) :
>   predictLearner for classif.h2o.deeplearning has returned not the class
>   levels as column names: p0,p1

If I change predict.type to "response" it works. So how to predict probabilities?

Comment: Just FYI, I've not seen anyone use mlr (successfully or not) with h2o before.  Based on the above, I expect some integration needs to be done for it to work.

Comment: Not sure if this comment is still useful now that we know it is due to a bug, but for example this works (on a different computer however, where I needed to update R first): 
library(mlr)
data(iris)
iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa", "ja", "nein")
task = makeClassifTask(data = iris2, target = "Species")
lrn = makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type="prob")
model = train(lrn, task)
pred = predict(model, newdata=iris2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/commit/b3f31ae1856b8d83fa526186ab34ff148e03e194) and will be in the next release. Until then, you can install the Github version:

```
devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an error (Installation failed: Timeout was reached). Is there another way to install the Github version?

Comment: You can also clone the repository and do `R CMD INSTALL .` in it.